# TFS integration with Jenkins could not parse XML

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to implement a CI system in our development team using Jenkins.

I have a collection URL defined like http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/collection and accesing with my own credentials (administrator).

The problem is that i can not connect my TFS 2015 with jenkins getting the following error:

````
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:634)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:444)
    at ms.tfs.services.registration._03._RegistrationSoap12Service.getRegistrationEntries(_RegistrationSoap12Service.java:106)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:58)
Caused: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: The servers response could not be parsed as XML: {0}
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.RegistrationExceptionMapper.map(RegistrationExceptionMapper.java:18)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationData.newFromServer(RegistrationData.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationData(RegistrationClient.java:617)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntries(RegistrationClient.java:144)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.registration.RegistrationClient.getRegistrationEntries(RegistrationClient.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.findServiceLocation(PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.java:275)
    at ```
````

Comment: How did you configure the tfs plugin? Please follow the following link to re-config your plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin.

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT Thank you so much, i resolve the problem. Finally was my proxy server. I had to disable jenkins proxy configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a problem with my proxy server. I just disable proxy configuration in jenkins plugin management and it's works.